# Segmentation fault: 11 xcode 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault, xcode12

We have updated the xcode version 11.6 to 12.4 last week. Everything was working perfectly. After this update, We are getting this issue. We tried these steps:

```
-clean / re-build
-removed derived data
-removed valid-archs from build settings
-added arm64 to Excluded Architectures
-reboot mac
```

Still we are facing same issue. These logs doesn't give proper information of the class where we need change. These are the error logs we are getting when we try to run the app:

```
0 swift 0x000000010984e615 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 37
1 swift 0x000000010984d615 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 85
2 swift 0x000000010984ebcf SignalHandler(int) + 111
3 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff70f0f5fd _sigtramp + 29
4 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007f8a8a354900 _sigtramp + 18446743571622286112
5 swift 0x00000001057c537b emitApplyArgument((anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction&, 
swift::SILValue, swift::SILType, swift::irgen::Explosion&) + 283
6 swift 0x00000001057c441a (anonymous 
namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 3770
7 swift 0x00000001057a2d26 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 8982
8 swift 0x000000010563b457 
swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitGlobalTopLevel(llvm::StringSet<llvm::MallocAllocator>*) + 1607
9 swift 0x0000000105777c37 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::ModuleDecl, 
std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, 
swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::StringRef, swift::SourceFile, llvm::GlobalVariable*, 
llvm::StringSet<llvm::MallocAllocator>) + 1687
10 swift 0x00000001057a0781 swift::SimpleRequest<swift::IRGenSourceFileRequest, 
swift::GeneratedModule (swift::IRGenDescriptor), 
(swift::RequestFlags)9>::evaluateRequest(swift::IRGenSourceFileRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 
97
11 swift 0x000000010577c04c llvm::Expected<swift::IRGenSourceFileRequest::OutputType> 
swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::IRGenSourceFileRequest>(swift::IRGenSourceFileRequest 
const&) + 940
12 swift 0x000000010577829d swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions const&, 
swift::SourceFile&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> 
>, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::GlobalVariable*, 
llvm::StringSet<llvm::MallocAllocator>) + 269
13 swift 0x00000001053c21ba performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, 
swift::CompilerInvocation const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, 
std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl, 
swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver) + 3002
14 swift 0x00000001053b1d97 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const, void, 
swift::FrontendObserver*) + 20695
15 swift 0x0000000105332c27 main + 1255
16 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff70d12cc9 start + 1
17 libdyld.dylib 0x00000000000001ac start + 18446603338623407332

error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'ProjectName' from project 'ProjectName')
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsaZY.png)

These are the pods we are using:

```
pod 'p2.OAuth2', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'CryptoSwift', '0.8.3'
```

How we can fix this? Any help appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you get any fix to these error?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Not yet, I am looking for the new xcode version it might solve in newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, I've also done upgrade from Xcode 11.7 to 12.4 and got the same `Segmentation fault: 11` error on so many `Swift` files in my project and the weird part is, most of the times those error doesn't have proper description or reasoning.

I have spent around a week on this and found a solution which worked for me.

There's one `BUILD` setting called `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE`, just set this property to `Whole Module` and build your project. Now XCode will start giving you error with some understandable description. You can go ahead fix those error.

Once you resolved these errors, you can set this property back to it's previous value i.e. `Incremental`

[image]

> NOTE: It still won't give you the error line number but it will give
> you the class & method name where this error lies, also the error count will get reduced to the actual count.
> You can comment all the lines in that function and try to uncomment one (or more) at a
> time and build your project to find out the problematic line.

This is how I'm able to resolved these errors, hope this helps you in resolving yours.

Comment: I tried to change the SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE to Whole Module. But still i m not able to resolve the issue. It doesn't give the proper information

Comment: did error change in any way after changing this setting @SoftwareEngineer

Comment: i was looking for the wrong side. My problem is solved now. by changing SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE to Whole Module it gives the valuable information. thanks